# SQL Server Management Studio hangs on 100% during recovery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, recovery

I want to restore a bak file in SQL server 2008 (the backup was created on a SQL server 2005). I set the recovery to WITH NORECOVERY, as I want to apply further transaction logs later.

Meaning: the database should stay in restore mode, but the recovery-dialog in the management studio does not finish ever. It shows 100% for nearly 20 hours. If I click "stop action now", the recovery failed.

I need to set WITH NORECOVERY (instead WITH RECOVERY) as I want to apply the transaction logs later. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing cumulative update 7 for SQL server 2008 SP1. Seems like in CU 1 included a hotfix for restoring 2005 backups on 2008 server.